# QEMU not installing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, qemu, failed-installation

After `./configure` it's showing this error:

> ```
> ERROR: pixman >= 0.21.8 not present. Your options:
>          (1) Preferred: Install the pixman devel package (any recent
>              distro should have packages as Xorg needs pixman too).
>          (2) Fetch the pixman submodule, using:
>              git submodule update --init pixman
> ```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpixman-1.0-dev`

Comment: @KenWhite "install the pixman devel package" -> "libpixman-1.0-dev" is a near impossible translation. "Package" doesn't imply "library", "dev" or "devel" is generally ambiguous in packages, and there would be no way to guess 1.0 is needed in there as well

Comment: https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux#Building_QEMU_for_Linux

Answer (score 41):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. For me helped installation below component:

```
sudo apt-get install libpixman-1-dev
```

Comment: Thank you! If only the error messages called the required packages by the names that the repository uses!

Comment: Works for debian too